# Gnome session - deleted by mistake the status menu at right in bottom panel

Tags: 12.04, gnome

i don't know how to search my problem cause i don't know how he call the things on the bottom bar at unity.

I installed Gnome fallback from ubuntu software center and i choose GNOME CLASSIC ( no effects )

[image: This is the bottom bar things]

and two minutes later i deleted by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete from Panel</kbd> option.

and it turned into:

[image: this one]

(i add the logout button to go back to unity to write this question)

the problem is not in unity but in gnome session.

[Unity picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNh6r.png)

[Gnome (after my stupid action) picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frWpv.png)

I used this [GUIDE](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/classicgnome) to take the idea to download Gnome. And i looked only the 12.04 guide.

i think that my question is useful, please add comments below if i miss to say something that is important.
Thanks, George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fount the solution!
http://prntscr.com/2qex3v

I just added the **Indicator Applet Complete**